# ¿Como saber si varios periodos de tiempo se solapan?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, datetime

Necesito iterar un array de objetos fecha, con duración y obtener con cuantas se solapa cada una de ellas.

Pero busco hacerlo de una forma eficiente y rápida. Estoy buscando frameworks para manejo de periodos de tiempo pero no he encontrado nada.

He desarrollado esto, pero realmente no funciona bien.

```
function numeroSolapacionesSesiones(sesion, lista)
{
    var sesiones = new Array();

    if(lista != null && lista.length > 0)
    {
        var fecha = convierteCadenaFechaHoraIsoFechaLocal(sesion.fechaCelebracionStr);
        var hora = fecha.substring(11,16);  
        var paramsHora = hora.split(":");
        var duracion = 90;
        var horasDuracion = duracion/60;
        var minutosRestoDuracion = duracion%60;
        var minutosTotalesConDuracion = parseInt(paramsHora[1]) + minutosRestoDuracion;
        var horasSumables = minutosTotalesConDuracion/60;
        var minutosFinales = minutosTotalesConDuracion%60;

        var horaInicio = parseInt(paramsHora[0]);
        var horaFinal = parseInt(paramsHora[0]) + horasSumables;
        var minutoInicio = parseInt(paramsHora[1]);
        var minutoFinal = minutosFinales;


        for(var numSesion in lista)
        {           
            var sesionItem = lista[numSesion];
            var fechaItem = convierteCadenaFechaHoraIsoFechaLocal(sesionItem.fechaCelebracionStr);
            var horaItem = fechaItem.substring(11,16);  
            var paramsHoraItem = horaItem.split(":");
            var duracionItem = 90;

            var horasDuracionItem = duracionItem/60;
            var minutosRestoDuracionItem = duracionItem%60;
            var minutosTotalesConDuracionItem = parseInt(paramsHoraItem[1]) + minutosRestoDuracionItem;
            var horasSumablesItem = minutosTotalesConDuracionItem/60;
            var minutosFinalesItem = minutosTotalesConDuracionItem%60;

            var horaInicioItem = parseInt(paramsHoraItem[0]);
            var horaFinalItem = parseInt(paramsHoraItem[0]) + horasSumablesItem;
            var minutoInicioItem = parseInt(paramsHoraItem[1]);
            var minutoFinalItem = minutosFinalesItem;

            if(horaInicio == horaInicioItem || horaFinal == horaInicioItem || horaInicio == horaFinalItem)
            {

                if(!(horaFinal == horaInicioItem && minutoFinal < minutoInicioItem || horaInicio == horaFinalItem && minutoFinalItem < minutoInicio))               
                {                   
                    sesiones.push(sesionItem);                                  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sesiones;

}
```

Comment: mírate la librería moments.js talvez te sirva para tu proposito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si buscas una libreria la mejor que he usado es [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Existe una extension en base a esta para poder trabajar con rangos

[moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range)

Podrias hacer

```
var start  = new Date(2012, 4, 1);
var end    = new Date(2012, 4, 23);

var range  = moment.range(start, end);

var dateInRange    = new Date(2012, 4, 15);
range.contains(dateInRange); //return true
```

Como veras es muy simple crear rangos y depsues validar si esta contenido

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate si al momento de hacer el chequeo puedes convertir las fechas a timestamps, eso facilitará el cálculo ya que los timestamps son simples valores numéricos. Los timestamps son una forma de medir el tiempo en segundos. Concretamente, un timestamp es la cantidad de segundos que transcurrieron desde el 01/01/1970. Por ejemplo, el timestamp de 01/01/2016 a las 00:00:00 es `1451606400`

Si puedes pasarlos a timestamp, entonces puedes usar esta función súper simple para chequear si se solapan

```
function hayInterseccion(desde1, hasta1, desde2, hasta2) {
    if (desde2 <= desde1 && hasta2 >= hasta1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (desde2 >= desde1 && hasta2 <= hasta1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (desde2 <= desde1 && hasta2 <= hasta1 && hasta2 > desde1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (desde2 >= desde1 && hasta2 >= hasta1 && desde2 < hasta1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado bien! Muchas gracias.